# Rest Api Anchor Tagging for Sign Here Tab xml format

Tags: docusignapi

we need to add anchor tagging in SignHereTab of REST Api. Please see below code. I did not find any suitable example for this, tried with below code but it's not working. Please check the code & reply with corrections needed in this. Also, if you have code example for the same, please share.

```
if (EmailRegex(strSalesRepApprover.ToString().Trim().Split(',')[1]))
                {
                    string strSigner = "<signer>" +
                       "<recipientId>" + iRecipientIdCouter + "</recipientId>" +
                       "<routingOrder>1</routingOrder>" +
                       "<email>" + strSalesRepApprover.ToString().Trim().Split(',')[1] + "</email>" +
                        "<name>" + strSalesRepApprover.ToString().Trim().Split(',')[0] + "</name>" +
                        "<tabs>" +
                        "<signHereTabs>" +
                         "<anchorString>Sales Initial</anchorString>" +
                        "<anchorXOffset>1</anchorXOffset>" +
                        "<anchorYOffset>0.5</anchorYOffset>" +
                        "<anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>" +
                        "<anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>" +
                        "</signHereTabs>" +
                        "</tabs>" +
                        "</signer>";
                    sbSalesRep_Customer_Contract.Append(strSigner);

                    //Add new item to Temp List
                    AddNew_SignerTempList(web, strOpportunityId, listCASignerTemp, strSalesRepApprover, "Sales");

                    iRecipientIdCouter++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To translate a given JSON body to its equivalent XML form, whenever you have an array of an array in JSON, like

```
"signHereTabs" : 
    {
        [
        ...
```

That will always translate into two xml nodes.  In this case, you need a singular `<signHere>` tab for each individual signing tab you want to add:

```
<signHereTabs>
    <signHere>
    ...
    </signHere>
</signHereTabs>
```

Here is what your `signHereTabs` should look like in XML format, along with some other optional properties that you can set for it:

```
<signHereTabs>
    <signHere>
        <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>sample string 14</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
        <anchorString>sample string 10</anchorString>
        <anchorUnits>sample string 13</anchorUnits>
        <anchorXOffset>sample string 11</anchorXOffset>
        <anchorYOffset>sample string 12</anchorYOffset>
        <conditionalParentLabel>sample string 16</conditionalParentLabel>
        <conditionalParentValue>sample string 17</conditionalParentValue>
        <documentId>sample string 5</documentId>
        <pageNumber>sample string 7</pageNumber>
        <recipientId>sample string 6</recipientId>
        <tabId>sample string 15</tabId>
        <xPosition>sample string 8</xPosition>
        <yPosition>sample string 9</yPosition>
        <name>sample string 1</name>
        <optional>sample string 4</optional>
        <scaleValue>3.1</scaleValue>
        <tabLabel>sample string 2</tabLabel>
    </signHere>
</signHereTabs>
```